# THREE.js: How to make rotation and translate use quaternion

Tags: three.js

I have these:

a translation:

```
[x1, y1, z1]
```

a quaternion:

```
[x, y, z, w]
```

how can I use the translation and quaternion to make rotation and translate with a three.js mesh.

also, can I combine these into one 4X4 matrix, which is used for mesh.applyMatrix()?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var obj = new THREE.Object3D()
obj.position.set(x1,y1,z1)
obj.quaternion.set(x,y,z,w)
obj.updateMatrix();

yourMesh.applyMatrix(obj.matrix)
```